# Using the REST API filter, including two meta_queries breaks the response for one custom post type

Tags: filters, rest-api

I'm using the [WP REST API filter parameter](https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter) plugin to be able to add filters to my REST requests.

This works fine.

Except, suddenly, adding two meta queries returns an Internal Server Error for, it seems, all post types.

So, this is a problem:

```
https://example.com/a/v4/wp-json/wp/v2/membership?_embed&_fields=_links,acf&page=1&filter[meta_query][0][key]=role&filter[meta_query][0][value]=admin&filter[meta_query][0][compare]=%27=%27&filter[meta_query][1][key]=group&filter[meta_query][1][value]=621227&filter[meta_query][1][compare]=%27=%27
```

These are not:

```
https://example.com/a/v4/wp-json/wp/v2/membership?_embed&_fields=_links,acf&page=1&filter[meta_query][0][key]=role&filter[meta_query][0][value]=admin&filter[meta_query][0][compare]=%27=%27

https://example.com/a/v4/wp-json/wp/v2/membership?_embed&_fields=_links,acf&page=1&filter[meta_query][1][key]=group&filter[meta_query][1][value]=621227&filter[meta_query][1][compare]=%27=%27
```

Beyond a doubt, this worked up till very recently.

I modify my API responses, but this problem persists after removing all my modifications.

I have no idea where to start looking for what could be the underlying problem. Any ideas would be great.

FWIW, removing the `_embed` and `_fields` parameters makes no difference.

Update: I've been able to replicate this on another Wordpress install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly, the cause of the problem seems to be the quotation marks around the comparison parameter.

For example `filter[meta_query][0][compare]=%27=%27` now needs to be `filter[meta_query][0][compare]==`.

When only matching one meta value, this is not necessary, when matching two, this is, now, necessary. :/

Update: I realised that my hosting provider changed the version of Linux on my server around the same time. I can imagine this might be connected.